# Can I translate/duplicate an existing graph in Excel into Python?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, plotly, bokeh

I have many graphs in Excel that I would like to convert to Python but am struggling with how to do so using Matplotlib. Is there a package or method that would essentially convert/translate all the formatting and data series selection into python? 
Once I could see a few examples of the correct code I think I could start doing this directly in python but I do not have much experience manually creating graph code (I use Excel insert graphs mostly) so am looking for a bridge.

Comment: Since you are working in Excel, I would recommend the Pandas python package. You can export your data from Excel (for example in the CSV format) and read it using Pandas. You haven't really asked a question specific enough to answer properly, I would recommend trying to replicate a specific graph yourself first and then ask about it on here :-)

Comment: The question was around whether there was a tool that could do this automatically rather than having to code it specifically. I found that plotly (https://plot.ly/create/#/) has an online graph creator that is close to what I'm looking for and lets you see the python code that was used to create it but again, not something that I can export. Is there a VBA to Python converter?

Comment: Trying to convert something like the following to a python package:
Sub test()
    ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub